# AND gate working in Multisim circuit but not AND IC 7408

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, multisim

I am a newbie in electronics.  I was trying to replicate this traffic control diagram:

[image: my basis]

I recreated the circuit in Multisim using 2 clocks and an AND gate, the 3 LEDs light up:

[image: multisim circuit with and gate]

If I replace the AND gate with a 7408 IC, the green LED does not light up anymore and I am not sure why.

I put the 2 inputs and 1 output wire according to its pin diagram and I connected the VCC and ground.

[image]

I can't figure out why the green LED won't light up.

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack Exchange. As soon as you start using net labels in EDA software instead of routing wires, your confusion will immediately reduce by 50%.

Comment: The above comment is not generally true IMHO

Comment: Which IC are you using for the D-type flip flops?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, it also now worked grounding set and reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the 7408 and...

Ask yourself what the reset pin on the D type flip flop does when it is set high: -

[image]

Fix the basic circuit first.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your assumption, the 74LS08 supply is not connected to the 5V VCC supply.

Answer (score 0):

TTL logic is not a good choice for driving LEDs, particularly green, blue, or white LEDs.

TTL logic families have a very weak ability to **source** current and their output voltages for a logic 1 are significantly less than 3V. I would expect that your red LED would glow weakly but green would not be illuminated at all.

You also need to remember that trying to drive an LED with a TTL logic gate is likely to cause the gate's output **voltage** to be an invalid logic level. If you use the output of a gate to drive an LED then don't use that output as an input to any other logic gates.

The best idea is to use a completely separate driver for LEDs. Add an open-collector TTL chip like the 7406 or 7407 or use discrete transistors to drive each LED.